# Error building project after Xcode 15.0 upgrade (error - Info.plist Error Unable to process Info.plist at path ..../Info.plist)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode15

Error building project after Xcode 15.0 upgrade (error -  Info.plist Error Unable to process Info.plist at path ..../Info.plist)

> Info.plist Error Unable to process Info.plist at path
> /Users/Ramprasath/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP-dubehduffxccjhazxzxzx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app/Info.plist

**Note:**
We are not using any runscripts.